# Multi site operate by single admin panel in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, master-slave, multisite

I want to create multisite in Drupal in which I want one master site and another sub sites operate by only one admin panel, single DB(different prefixes)

Eg.

www.red.com

blue.red.com

green.red.com

One admin panel for all these sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Domain Access Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) for multi-site you can edit anything with 1 admin panel no need to login in subsite.

Module give facility to publish content on specific domain(Affiliated content) and you can change it form backend.

Also you can Restrict user domain wise.